# External files into 2d arrays

Tags: java, arrays

So I've been researching on how to place an external file into a 2d array using a scanner. However, I don't really understand how to make it work and I was hoping I could get some help on how to write it. For example, if I have a file that looks like this (5x5):

45 67 89 12 -3

-3 -6 -7 -4 -9

96 81 -8 52 12

14 -7 72 29 -1

19 43 28 63 87

Then I read the file with the scanner with this(very rough outline):

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("Insert File Location"));
while(reader.hasNext())
{
```

How can I store this data into a 2d array using this format? I'm not really sure on how it works and I have an exam in a couple of weeks. I was planning on asking my professor, but he hasn't been here for the last few days. Could someone please show me how I can do this to store the file into a 2d array? If there are any other ways that may be more efficient, I would be open to all ideas (still a beginner). I really appreciate all the help.

Comment: this has been asked and answered multiple times already.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading from a .txt into a 2D array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13500432/reading-from-a-txt-into-a-2d-array)

Answer (score 0):

Create a 5 by 5 2D array of int and call the `nextInt()`(means it must be a int not a string or you'll get an error) of the Scanner

try this code

```
 int array[][] = new int[5][5];
    int counter1 = 0;
    int counter2 = 0;
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("Insert File Location"));
    while(reader.hasNext())
    {
        array[counter1][counter2++] = reader.nextInt();
        array[counter1][counter2++] = reader.nextInt();
        array[counter1][counter2++] = reader.nextInt();
        array[counter1][counter2++] = reader.nextInt();
        array[counter1][counter2++] = reader.nextInt();
        ++counter1;
        counter2 = 0;
    }
```